# Cannot interpolate on Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error, interpolation, dataframe

I am trying to interpolate missing values on my Pandas Dataframe:

```
              a   b    c
2013-11-19   20   28  55 
2013-11-20   27   29  54
2013-11-21  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-11-22  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-11-23  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013-11-14   34   62   89
```

unfortunately if I try to use

```
df1 = df1.interpolate()
```

i get the following error message:

```
TypeError: interpolate() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This does work for me. What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: I have version 0.12.0

Comment: Upgraded to 0.13.1 and now working! Many thanks

Comment: Actually, to clarify. `DataFrame.interpolate` was deprecated in 0.12, and added again with in 0.13 but with other behaviour (as previously `Series.interpolate`). In 0.12 is was more something like `.replace/.fillna`, and as you can see in the docstring, you needed to give a `to_replace` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of pandas resolves this issue.
If you still want to use interpolate without upgrading pandas use can do this:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col] = df1[col].interpolate()
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464738/interpolation-on-dataframe-in-pandas)  for more info.