# pandas.rolling is not ignoring NaN when having datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I was trying to use `roll` to find mean of previous 6 days value. The following code is not ignoring `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
xx =pd.DataFrame(list(zip([datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x*60*60*24*2) for x in range(0,16,2)],[2,1,3,np.nan, 4,5,6,7])), columns=["datetime", "val"])
xx.set_index("datetime", inplace=True)
xx.rolling(str(6)+'d',1).apply(lambda x : np.nanmean(x))
```

The above code gives:

```
                     val
datetime                
1969-12-31 18:00:00  2.0
1970-01-04 18:00:00  1.5
1970-01-08 18:00:00  2.0
1970-01-12 18:00:00  NaN
1970-01-16 18:00:00  4.0
1970-01-20 18:00:00  4.5
1970-01-24 18:00:00  5.5
1970-01-28 18:00:00  6.5
```

However, if I remove datetime series index,

```
xx = pd.DataFrame([2,1,3,np.nan, 4,5,6,7],
                 columns=["val"])
yy = xx.rolling(3,1).apply(lambda x : np.nanmean(x))
```

the `NaN` is ignored:

```
   val
0  2.0
1  1.5
2  2.0
3  2.0
4  3.5
5  4.5
6  5.0
7  6.0
```

Much appreciation to any help!

## Update

This is a bug and was fixed here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17156

Comment: `xx.rolling(str(6)+'d',1)` does not for me: `ValueError: window must be an integer`. Did you paste the correct code?

Comment: tested on both py3.6 and py2.7 it works for me. my pandas is 0.20.3 if that helps. I think rolling on datetime is only after 0.19.0

Comment: This could be a bug https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed as a bug and was fixed here 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17156

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to interpolate your dataframe or you could also back or forward fill with fillna().

Try this code:

```
xx.interpolate(inplace=True)
yy = xx.rolling(str(6)+'d',1,).apply(lambda x : np.nanmean(x))
```

Tested and its working

Found Similar Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234782/pandas-rolling-mean-with-nan-values)

Comment: Thanks. However I can't use interpolate as it impacts desired value. Although careful interpolation can avoid it but it would be depending on what function to apply (`np.nanmean` is just used as example here)