# Converting DatetimeIndex to Timedelta index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given:

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(['2014-01-08 08:00:42',
                     '2014-01-08 08:01:00',
                     '2014-01-08 08:01:12'])
```

Is there a prescribed way to get a result that is the timedelta (preferably `total_seconds` attribute) between each element?

What I have now seems overly verbose:

```
pd.Index((pd.Series(ts) - pd.Series(ts).shift())).total_seconds()
# Float64Index([nan, 18.0, 12.0], dtype='float64')
```

I don't really care about the resulting data structure type, be it a list, Index, or Series.

Comment: `ts.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds().values`?

Comment: @Zero why not submit an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.diff` in this way.

```
np.diff(ts.values).astype(int) / 1E9

array([ 18.,  12.])
```

Or

```
np.append(np.nan, np.diff(ts.values).astype(int) / 1E9)

array([ nan,  18.,  12.])
```

Comment: I prepended an `np.nan` but adds to the verbosity

Comment: You need `np.append(np.nan, (np.diff(ts.values) // 1E9).astype(int))` I think?

Comment: Since, we are at it, `[np.nan] + (np.diff(ts.values) // 1E9).tolist()` perhaps?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between your first suggestion and what I proposed.  I used `astype(int)` to cast away from `timedelta[ns]`.  After that, I don't think the ordering of when you do the casting changes the final outcome.  For your second suggestion, I can't be certain without testing... but I'm willing to bet there is a performance hit.

Comment: Ah, `np.diff(ts.values).astype(int) // 1E9` gives me `array([ 0., -1.])` hence asking to move `astype`

Comment: Whoops `//` is unnecessary.  I removed it.  I would be different for python 2 vs 3.  I'm assuming you're using python 2.

Comment: Yes, single `/` too doesn't work on Python2 atleast.